# Socket only Receives The First Send and the others will be just Empty

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, connection

Guys So I'm new at programming and this is the first programming language that I am learning.

I need some help with networking

I tried to Make Client/Server Connection. At first, I had a Problem to make the server Receives from more than one client but I fixed that

now I got another problem the server only Receives The First Message and the other message is just Empty or null. Why is that?

```
 new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                StartRec();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }).Start();


private static void StartRec()
    {
        if (ClientsList.Count > 0)
        {
            //Buffer = new byte[1024];
            foreach (Socket C in ClientsList)
            {
                C.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(EndRec), C);
            }
        }
    }


private static void EndRec(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket _C = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int rec = _C.EndReceive(ar);
        if (rec > 0)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref Buffer, rec);
            string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer);
            BackLog(result, true);
            Buffer = new byte[1024];
            StartRec();
        }
        else
        {
            StartRec();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A major problem is that you call StartRec on the EndRec, which will initiate BeginReceive on each connection. You should call BeginReceive directly in the EndRec.

Comment: it's a little confusing, you are using `BeginReceive` which is supposed to work asynchronously in a synchronous fashion in a while loop, which is situated in a background thread which is supposed to make it asynchronously again. Actually you shold do either of those things. Either use the background thread and the while loop and try to read in the loop from the socket, or forget about the thread and the loop and simply use `BeginReceive` which has to be called in the beginning and then every time in `EndRec` like @JeroenvanLangen told you